# google ad-sense is not populating the ads in my website

Tags: adsense

I am trying to populate google ad-sense into my client website and i am using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-adsense

With view page source on msbionlineclasses.com you can see on the index page the directive is been called. [image: Image attached]

Still i am getting a blank item. Let me know the reason?

Update-1

I am getting as AD:1

[image: Refer Image]

Comment: Usually google takes 24-48 hours to  start showing ads.

Comment: I am waiting for more than  a week. you mean to say after i implement the code into html or after registration.

Answer (score 0):

Usually google starts analysing your website traffic patterns and content type once your adsense code goes live i.e. after implementing it into your HTML page.

For few days (usually 1-2 days), it will only show the empty placeholders, which is the case with you right now I guess.

Wait for 2 days and you will be able to see the results automatically.

**P.S.** - the usual practice I follow is to have only one adsense implementation in the footer where empty placeholder will not bother the visitors as well as the look of the page. Once it is working, implement as desired.

Comment: Hi..Can you look into my update 1.. It says AD:1 now. but the ad is not displayed.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Looks like the implementation issue. May be a good idea to refer soe similar implementation. Please see if this is working for you : http://leonardteo.github.io/google-ads-test-angularjs/#/page1

Comment: For first two loads the demo page was showing me the advt after that it stopped. I implemented the code into my project. Still i see a blank page. Any possibility you can help me by developer tools from your end. Its msbionlineclasses.com.

Comment: Looking at code might work rather than looking at the custom html